# Why isn't the Ubuntu terminal interactive?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I'm very new to Ubuntu.

If I do:

```
rm removeText
```

The terminal is doing it *silently.* Why can't it say:

> removeText removed

or something similar? I'd like this so that every time I remove a file, I don't have to execute `ls` to see if the file has been removed or not.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: usually the terminal will only return text if something went wrong.

btw just to be pedantic (or provide un-asked-for info) this isn't an ubuntu behaviour, it's a unix/linux behaviour, ie is shared by all unix derived OSs, of which ubuntu is just one example.  The "rm -i" command @slhck mentions is actually an override added by bash, which is the standard shell, ie input handling program.  The unix-basic rm doesn't have an "-i" option. Just saying in case you're one of those people who likes to read around the subject a bit :)

Comment: @MaxWilliams On my Ubuntu system, `rm` is `/bin/rm` from Coreutils and not a shell builtin, and it offers `rm -i`. Am I missing something?

Comment: As is already said but maybe not as clearly, to directly address your last question: you don't have to use `ls` to see if the file has been removed, since it _will_ be removed unless you are told otherwise by `rm`.

Comment: @DanielAndersson True, that somehow didn't come across as clearly as I wanted. Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it trusts you to know what you're doing. Normally, Unix and Linux commands only tell you if something went wrong, and will stay quiet otherwise. This makes the commands so easy to use in scripts or when chained together – you will have to tell them that you want a specific output.

So, if there had been a problem removing a file, you would have received an error.

#### Getting a confirmation dialog:

If you want a confirmation dialog before removing a file, use `rm -i` or `rm -I` (the latter is available on GNU/Linux, and not on OS X or any BSD-derived systems):

```
   -i     prompt before every removal

   -I     prompt once before removing more than three files, or when removing recursively.  Less intrusive than -i, while still giv‐
          ing protection against most mistakes
```

#### Knowing what was removed:

If you just want to see which file was removed, use `rm -v` (v for "verbose", a flag present in many command-line tools). You can also alias your `rm` to use `rm -v` instead by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) on how to do that).

```
alias rm='rm -v'
```

The alias will "replace" the built-in command with the one on the right hand of the expression.

#### A word of caution:

Note that aliasing built-in commands is often considered bad practice. Why? If you find yourself getting used to getting confirmation dialogs, and suddenly you are on another system,  type `rm /some/important/file`, you'll end up removing a file you didn't want to, and it'll be gone. Forever.

I'd suggest you learn to live with the defaults unless you absolutely feel confident around the Linux shell.

Also, always read `man rm` – or generally the manpages of commands you want to use. They often provide additional information about common mistakes, further flags, and other caveats.

Comment: +1 for your word of caution. Years ago as a fledgling sysadmin, I was bitten by this exact thing, having aliased "dangerous" commands for my own user account. The first week I had true root access, I botched a shell glob and deleted a year's worth of system logs. I didn't double-check that the command was going to do what I wanted since I was used to the `remove /path/to/file? [y/N]` prompts being a safety net. Fortunately the lesson was learned with just the one mistake :)